# Change Underscore to Dash in Apache Header

Tags: apache-2.4, authentication, http-headers

I have an application that runs behind Apache 2.4.27 that authenticates users with mod_auth_cas. This module stores attributes about the authenticated user in headers. I'm having issues with one header that's being stripped because it has an underscore in it (`X-CAS-email_primary`). After doing some searching, I added the code snippet below to the VirtualHost configuration.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase X-CAS-email_primary ^(.*)$ fix_header=$1
RequestHeader set X-CAS-email-primary %{fix_header}e env=fix_header
```

In case it wasn't obvious, I'm trying to change `X-CAS-email_primary` to `X-CAS-email-primary`. This code is partially working. The new header does appear but it has no value.

```
["HTTP_X_CAS_EMAIL_PRIMARY"]=> string(0) ""
```

I've confirmed that `X-CAS-email_primary` is set, so I'm not quite sure what's going on. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of a `RequestHeader set` supports expressions, and expressions include the `req` (or `http`) function, which gives you the value of request headers. So this one directive should do what you want:

```
RequestHeader set X-CAS-email-primary "expr=%{req:X-CAS-email_primary}"
```

You have to dig deep into the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader) to find this kind of thing, but it's there.

Not sure why your configuration didn't work, but I guess the SetEnvIfNoCase is evaluated after the RequestHeader. The docs don't make it easy to figure that out.