# Apache Underscore in Header is overwriten

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, http-headers

I've a service which sets the header x-user_type. Since Apache2.4.33 cannot use this, i'll transform this with the following in a .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        SetEnvIfNoCase ^x.user.type$ ^(.*)$ fix_x-user_type=$1
        RequestHeader set x-user-type %{fix_x-user_type}e env=fix_x-user_type
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

But if i supply x-user-type within a request then the value for x-user-type in the response is overwritten

Examples:

- Nothing supplied -> x-user-type = application (This is set by the service)
- x-user_type = test -> x-user-type = application (This is ok, since it is set by the service)
- x-user-type = test -> x-user-type = test (This should be application as well)

I think this is an apache configuration issue. Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed my own Problem with this: https://serverfault.com/a/900745/490242

Quote:

> The value of a `RequestHeader set` supports expressions, and expressions include the `req` (or http) function, which gives you the value of request headers. So this one directive should do what you want:
>
> `RequestHeader set X-CAS-email-primary "expr=%{req:X-CAS-email_primary}"`
>   You have to dig deep into the documentation to find this kind of thing, but it's there.
>
> Not sure why your configuration didn't work, but I guess the SetEnvIfNoCase is evaluated after the RequestHeader. The docs don't make it easy to figure that out.

Seems like `SetEnvIfNoCase` was my problem too.

Comment: If someone has a similar problem where they want/need to support both cases of the header (e.g. `X-CAS-email-primary` and `X-CAS-email_primary`), the [RequestHeader directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader) also has the method `setifempty` which won't overwrite the header if it is already set (available in 2.4.7 and later).